# How to check if is a number divisible

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-datalab

Why my program does not work? I want to print n in every cycle, which it will be comparing if number n is divisible by 2, or divisible by 3 and 5 or divisible by none of these numbers.  Thanks for help.

```
funkcia = function(n){
    for (i in 1:n){
        if (n/2 == 0){
            n = n*n
            print (n)
            
        }
        else if(n/3 == 0 & n/5 == 0){
            n =n*n*n
            print(n)
            
        }
        
        else {
            n = n
            print(n)
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Read about `%%` and `%/%`, see `?Arithmetic`. Also, read about floating points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: `n/2 == 0` only occurs when n == 0...

Comment: To zx8754's comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html